# Join arguments into one string

Tags: go

I have this:

```
if t.FieldName != "" {
        if t.FieldName != item.FieldName {
            panic(errors.New("FieldName does not match, see: ", t.FieldName, item.FieldName))
        }
}
```

that won't compile because errors.New takes one string arg. So I need to do something like:

```
panic(errors.New(joinArgs("FieldName does not match, see: ", t.FieldName, item.FieldName)))
```

How can I implement joinArgs, so that it concatenates all it's strings arguments into one string?

Comment: aren't you just looking for the `fmt.Sprint*` functions?

Comment: idk, that's why I asked tha question, I think the answer I posted works tho, but haven't really tested it that much

Comment: yes, it probably works, but reading the `fmt` package docs would show you a number of simpler ways to format strings with the provided functions.

Comment: If it's so simple please add an answer demonstrating how, upvote guaranteed over here

Comment: 0
down vote

The XY problem is asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem: [The XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Your real problem is formatting error messages.

Comment: As an aside from your compilation problem, if you used log.Panic(...) It would work.

Answer (score 2):

The XY problem is asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem: [The XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Your real problem is formatting `panic` error messages.

---

This is the normal solution to your real problem:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    t := struct{ FieldName string }{FieldName: "a t.FieldName"}
    item := struct{ FieldName string }{FieldName: "an item.FieldName"}

    panic(fmt.Sprintf("FieldName does not match, see: %v %v", t.FieldName, item.FieldName))
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/DaOlcqUgV_H

Output:

```
panic: FieldName does not match, see: a t.FieldName an item.FieldName
```

Comment: best explanation of XY problem btw, thanks for explaining that

Comment: I am not a fan of string interpolation like that, hate it in all languages lol

Comment: But it might be useful in some cases, so thanks... Sprintf is a poor name, btw, there is no printing to stdout here, so why "print"? dumb.

Comment: related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53026706/use-fmt-printf-to-format-string

Comment: @AlexanderMills: `sprint` i.e "string" print is a common prefix for these functions in many languages, and included in the POSIX standard. It's chosen because of broad familiarity.

Comment: Yeah C/C++ has that naming pattern, why not continue a bad thing lol

Answer (score -2):

This seemed to work, not sure if it's optimal tho

```
func joinArgs(strangs ...string) string {
    buffer := bytes.NewBufferString("")
    for _, s := range strangs {
        buffer.WriteString(s)
    }
    return buffer.String()
}
```

Comment: This is a bad solution to the problem. This is a bad solution to the question. For the question, there is a [`strings.Join`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Join).

Comment: strings.Join takes an array as first arg, hardly convenient here. Not sure what is so bad about this solution.

Comment: [strings.Join](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Join) is simple,  easy, well-known, and idiomatic: https://play.golang.org/p/7g8cqk7iq5p

Comment: @peterSO the strings.Join api is not that cool IMO, the signature for `strings.Join` should be this instead `func Join(sep string, strangs ...string) string`, more generic that way, oh well. the API I just mentioned is why I implemented how I did in my answer here.