# Refer to the same parameter multiple times in a fmt.Sprintf format string

Tags: go, string-formatting

I have this function:

```
func getTableCreationCommands(v string) string {
    return `
        CREATE TABLE share_` + v + ` PARTITION OF share FOR VALUES IN (` + v + `);
        CREATE TABLE nearby_` + v + ` PARTITION OF nearby FOR VALUES IN (` + v + `);
    `
}
```

It's a little wonky... is there a way to format the string using `fmt.Sprintf`?

Something like this:

```
func getTableCreationCommands(v string) string {
    return fmt.Sprintf(`
        CREATE TABLE share_%v PARTITION OF share FOR VALUES IN (%v);
        CREATE TABLE nearby_%v PARTITION OF nearby FOR VALUES IN (%v);
    `, v, v, v, v)
}
```

but without the need to pass `v` 4 times?

Comment: Stop manually creating SQL statements now and forever!

Comment: @Volker, in this particular case, a typical parameter escaping done by SQL drivers won't work. And unfortunately, this approach to sort of "manual sharding" of data into several tables is not unheard of (at least in MySQL world).

Answer (score 49, accepted):

> [Package fmt](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/)
>
> ```
> import "fmt"
> ```
>
> Explicit argument indexes:
>
> In Printf, Sprintf, and Fprintf, the default behavior is for each
> formatting verb to format successive arguments passed in the call.
> However, the notation [n] immediately before the verb indicates that
> the nth one-indexed argument is to be formatted instead.

---

You can pass the variable `v` once. For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func getTableCreationCommands(s string) string {
    return fmt.Sprintf(`
        CREATE TABLE share_%[1]v PARTITION OF share FOR VALUES IN (%[1]v);
        CREATE TABLE nearby_%[1]v PARTITION OF nearby FOR VALUES IN (%[1]v);
    `, s)
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(getTableCreationCommands(("X")))
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/fKV3iviuwll

Output:

```
CREATE TABLE share_X PARTITION OF share FOR VALUES IN (X);
CREATE TABLE nearby_X PARTITION OF nearby FOR VALUES IN (X);
```

Comment: I think it should be %s not %v? idk

Comment: Also, a bit strange that the indexing starts at 1 instead of 0. But I guess if you wanted to grab the first argument in the function, you could do some weird recursion lol

Comment: I guess it starts with `1` because the `0-th`  is the format string

Comment: Using `%s` instead of `%v` would make this more type-safe, but in the case of a `string` value the result here is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `text/template`:

```
package same

import (
   "strings"
   "text/template"
)

func getTableCreationCommands(v string) string {
   t, b := new(template.Template), new(strings.Builder)
   template.Must(t.Parse(`
CREATE TABLE nearby_{{.}} PARTITION OF nearby FOR VALUES IN ({{.}});
CREATE TABLE share_{{.}} PARTITION OF share FOR VALUES IN ({{.}});
   `)).Execute(b, v)
   return b.String()
}
```

https://pkg.go.dev/text/template